# Toggle navigation only on smaller screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize, toggle

I have a menu which displays on its entirety on larger screens. However for screens between 1024px and 1400px I wish to hide the social icons which are part of this menu and only display them on the click of a button. This is working fine but after clicking the button which shows them if I then resize the window to a wider size the buttons don't show anymore. Ideally when the screen is between 1024px and 1400px the expand social icons button would display allowing me to see my social button on click of that button but then when resizing the window to a larger size it should automatically hide the expand social icons button and show them all but after clicking the expand social icons button and then resizing the window to a larger screen the social buttons do not display.

This is my toggle jquery code:

```
jQuery.fn.clickToggle = function (a, b) {
  function cb() {
   [b, a][this._tog ^= 1].call(this);
  }
   return this.on("click", cb);
};

$(".header-social-trigger").clickToggle(function () {
  $('.header-social').css("cssText", "display: table-cell!important");
  $('.dg-button, .mnr-header-button').css("cssText", "display: none");
  $('.header-social-trigger .icon').removeClass("ion-android-share-alt");
  $('.header-social-trigger .icon').addClass("ion-close");
}, function () {
  $('.header-social').css("cssText", "display: none");
  $('.dg-button, .mnr-header-button').css("cssText", "display: table-cell");
  $('.header-social-trigger .icon').removeClass("ion-close");
  $('.header-social-trigger .icon').addClass("ion-android-share-alt");
});
```

I have created a fiddle which illustrates the issue I am experiencing here https://jsfiddle.net/v5bgp389/18/. How could I basically make the code ignore the toggle code and display all buttons on larger screens?

Comment: Please break this down to several shorter sentences, I'm falling asleep before reaching the end :-) "Ideally when the screen is between 1024px and 1400px the expand social icons button would display allowing me to see my social button on click of that button but then when resizing the window to a larger size it should automatically hide the expand social icons button and show them all but after clicking the expand social icons button and then resizing the window to a larger screen the social buttons do not display."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*Change Css*/
        @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
            .header-social-trigger {
                display: table-cell !important;
                background-color: #e0771a !important;
                border-left: 0 !important;
            }

                .header-social-trigger:hover {
                    background-color: #f1811e !important;
                }

            .header-social {
                display: none !important;
            }
        }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
            .header-social-trigger {
                display:none !important;
                background-color: #e0771a !important;
                border-left: 0 !important;
            }

                .header-social-trigger:hover {
                    background-color: #f1811e !important;
                }

            .header-social {
                display: table-cell !important;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
if($(window).width() > 1024 && $(window).width() < 1400){
    //screen width between 1024 and 1400px
} 
else{ 
   //other screen sizes
}
```

?